# Texas Holdem odds evaluating package for Python

Tags: python, simulation

I write my master thesis on "Estimation of poker skills value in late tournament phase". I encountered a problem because i can not find python package which would evaluate hand odds versus each other.

What is satisfying for my is simply function:
odds(AsAc, KsKc) which would return [% that AsAc wins, % that KsKc wins]

I tried package PokerSleuth but it does not work on my pc.
(http://www.barsoom.org/scriptable-equity-calculator  - maybe it works for You)

Do You happen to know any python holdem package with function of odds estimation or do You posses a table with all hands vs all hands odds value?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Well there's not a package specifically made for cards I dont think but there's a package called random.
[random package docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html)

So for example if you had 8 cards and you threw them on the ground you could do this.

```
import random

cards = ["jack", "Queen","Ace", "King","Joker","12 of hearts", "6 of hearts","1 of hearts"]

pick = random.choice(cards)
print pick
#Output Example: Jack
```

This is a example of 8 card pick up
sorry for the names I dont know much about cards.